# I have to read a paper for my PhD qualifying exams but I don't understand any of it. Does that mean I fail?

Tags: phd

My committee assigned me to read a paper.  But there is a lot of notation I don't understand.  I tried looking at papers in the reference list and I can't really find anything that explains all the notation and concepts.  I also tried looking for talks that the author gave, but they don't go into as much detail as the paper.

What should I do?  I have no background in this field so I'm not really sure where to start.  I also have about three weeks to figure this out.

Edit: Please stop answering this question because apparently it might be cheating.

Comment: Go to whichever member of your committee suggested this paper and tell him or her exactly what you've told us.

Comment: See if there's a review paper that cites this one. The capsule summary and context might be helpful.

Comment: @user53076: You haven't gotten any content-related information about the paper you want to read, so I wouldn't worry that you have cheated on the project.

Comment: It's definitely not cheating to ask for how to approach a situation where you don't understand a particular paper!

Comment: How is learning for an exam cheating? The more information you shov into your head the better. That's the overall goal. How could learning with papers be cheating?

Comment: If you had asked "What does $r^2=x^2+y^2$ mean?", that *might* have been cheating according to some people.  Your very general question cannot be considered cheating.

Comment: I agree with the general advice to go to your committee and talk to them about this. And I would say that you should stress the part about the notation being undefined in the paper itself. This indicates the sort of paper that someone already familiar with the field can read but nobody else can, and this seems like a poor choice of paper for this purpose (if you had plenty of time to read and understand the paper, it might make for a good way to get familiar with the field, tracking down the notation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are unsure of your ability to complete the task, you should go immediately to your advisor and/or the other committee members to get as much help as they can give you.

That is not much of an answer, but I want to supplement it with this: in this case, asking for help on the internet is potentially problematic.  Being assigned a paper and asked to read and understand it in three weeks sounds like a situation which is close to a "take-home exam".  (Maybe it isn't, and maybe you are not understanding the assignment.  Find out.) If so, getting help on the internet on your exam may not be kosher.

Anyway, most graduate students in most graduate programs in most fields do not automatically or easily understand cutting edge papers.  The whole point of the graduate programs is to give them the help and training they need to do this.  So you should be doing what you can to get that help and training, not worrying about whether you are worthy in some cosmic sense.

Good luck.

**Added**: For those who are confused by the discrepancy between the answer and my comment above: the original version of the question included a lot of content-related information, including the title and author of the paper itself.  I was worried that could lead to getting content-related help from the internet.  The current version of the question is totally unproblematic in that regard.

Comment: Hmm, you may be right.  Let me delete the question.

Comment: I can't delete it so I just flagged it.

Comment: @user53076 asking for specific help might be cheating,. Asking for general help, like you have, is unlikely to be cheating.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question now.